# Wrong numeration of tables within main matter/Appendix

Tags: appendices

```
\appendix 
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

What is wrong with this command for the appendix of tables? I have two tables, one within the main matter and another one in the appendix. In the appendix it appears as "A1", but when I refer to it in the text it is referenced as "Tab A". And the table within the text appears as "1.1" but is indicated as "1.2" (probably because it has counted the table of the index as "1.1" or anything like that).

Comment: Are you sure you're putting `\label` after `\caption`?

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) is needed to see what you see and give proper advice.

Comment: I have just compiled this MWE: `\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\ref{one} - \ref{two}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{c}Merry Xmas\end{tabular}\caption{Merry Xmas...\label{one}}\end{table}
\appendix 
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{c}Happy New Year!\end{tabular}\caption{and a happy new year!\label{two}}\end{table}
\ref{one} - \ref{two}
\end{document}` and the named issues did not arise. Thus a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.